# Discord.py Permissions on roles

Tags: python, permissions, discord, bots, discord.py

Why does
`ctx.guild.default_role.permissions.change_nickname()`

Output this:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

In the doc it says:

```
@flag_value
def change_nickname(self):
  """:class:`bool`: Returns ``True`` if a user can change their nickname in the guild."""
  return 1 << 26
```

Comment: okay, thx now i get a return, but how can i CHANGE the Change_Nickname value by the value of a var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Editing Role Permissions on command

```
@client.command()
async def toggle(ctx):
    perms = discord.Permissions()
    perms.update(read_messages = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = False, change_nickname=True) 
    #add more permissions

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "role_name":
             await role.edit(reason = None, colour = discord.Colour.orange(), permissions=perms)
```

this will edit the role named `role_name`'s permissions to **also** 'can change nickname' :)

Answer (score 0):

`change_nickname` isn't a method, so you can't call it with parentheses. You would just write `ctx.guild.default_role.permissions.change_nickname`

Comment: okay, thx now i get a return, but how can i CHANGE the Change_Nickname value by a var?

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending the command into a channel, You need it to be a string and change nickname also isn't a method.

for this just use
perms = str(ctx.guild.defualt_role.permissions.change_nickname)

ctx.send(perms)

Comment: Please use code blocks when writing code to make it easier for the OP to understand.

Comment: okay, thx now i get a return, but how can i CHANGE the Change_Nickname value by a var?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
ctx.guild.default_role.permissions.change_nickname
```

Comment: okay, thx now i get a return, but how can i CHANGE the Change_Nickname value by a var?

Comment: i'll answer it below

Answer (score 0):

So like to toggle this setting of the default role. @BillyDev

[image: Nickname_Change Role permission]